# Anyone ever split I2C across two microcontrollers?

Tags: c, embedded, distributed, i2c

So I've got this wild idea to try and split an I2C controller implementation across two microcontrollers. That is, one uC controls the SDA and one uC controls the SCL, and communicate as one I2C device on the bus, master or slave. I'm not trying to just do basic I2C communications here, I want two physically separate controllers to work together as one I2C interface.

Anyone here ever do anything like this who could suggest how I might go about doing it?

I'm assuming my separate SDA and SCL controllers would have to be bit-banged, for starters, but I'm not sure about the rest. What kind of interprocessor communication would you use? SPI at a *much* higher rate seems like a place to start. How likely is this to work, and what kind of performance could one possibly expect out of such a system? Is it only possible at a few hundred Hz, maybe?

Are there any applications where this sort of thing is commonplace? Different protocols or whatever; the thing I'm wondering about is a hardware communications interface distributed across multiple controllers.

Comment: Maybe you tell us what your real problem is so we can help you better.

Comment: "wild idea" is one way to put it. There's absolutely no way that the benefits of doing this would outweigh the costs.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Google for "I2C muti master protocol" and look at [this post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115577/how-does-multimaster-i2c-work-and-its-significance).

Comment: Or another simple way, I can imagine,  is to build up a token ring between 2 MCUs that give the access to the shared resource as _time-sharing-if-no needed_.

Comment: I guess you don't know much about I2C. Here's an analogy to what you're asking. Cars are usually steered by two front wheels, controlled from a single steering wheel held by a single driver. Your question is like saying you have this wild idea to make the two front wheels each controlled by its own steering wheel, and have two drivers one at each wheel. Now, you want to know, what's the best way of getting this vehicle to work? is it to add some extra communication channel between the two drivers? How should I do that? I2C is designed to be (relatively) simple - why try to complicate it?

Comment: @barny Like your analogy so much I'd rather give a +2, if I could. SDA and SDL have extremely close timing dependencies (clock stretching, collision detection in multi-master operations,...) that I would even consider it impossible to implement properly - Just like your steering... Also, the benefits are similar ;)

Comment: So, how do you synchronise the two controllers?

Comment: @barny: Good analogy. But isn't making simple things complicated exactly what our industry is heading towards? ;-}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reason why to do this even, if it is "for fun" or "just because it is there" (why climb over the mountain when you can go around).

Look at how I2C works.  Both would have to be watching each others signals (or some other method to keep in sync), if you had SDA (The owner of that signal) watching SCL and vice versa.  Look at the waveform requirements, if both start high then SDA drops, the SCL owner sees that and drops SCL, the sda owner sees that and asserts the first bit.  Now we are already in trouble.  If the first bit is a zero the SCL owner doesnt know if SDA has set the bit yet so it cant raise SCL to clock it in.  There would have to be more information.  The SDA and SCL owners would have to agree on some rules, when SCL goes low the SDA owner has to agree to change its state if it is going to, within some window.  SCL has to agree to not change its state until after that window.  Then SDA can see SCL go high then low.  And repeat.  Or go with SCL cannot exceed the max rate for I2C or for this peripheral and SDA lives within that.  SDA can be happy with changing bits up until the ACK, if SCL is within spec for this peripheral and/or I2C then its okay (which is true even without this two owner scheme).  Your real problem comes when you want to stop, how does SCL know that SDA has done what it needed to do and go high and stay high?  So SDA can go high and stay high, and SCL goes back into the mode of waiting for SDA to initiate a start.  You need at least another signal between them that is not part of i2c, and you need this other agreement that SCL goes no faster than X and SDA meets that (cant arbitrarily state SCL goes at the max rate, because maybe SDA cant always keep up with that, maybe the peripheral can but maybe SDA cant, so your system design has to cover that).

Far far, easier just to do it with one owner of both signals.  Technically though it is possible, it doesnt gain you anything other than an interesting system design.  Folks that can scale rock faces have experience over those that just go around the mountain.

Arguably without a third signal you could have SDA change state twice fast, faster than the I2C clock speed agreed upon.  SCL could see this as the indication that you want to do a stop.  SCL then goes high stays high until it sees SDA go high then go low indicating another start.

Im trying to decide if SCL even has to stay there, can you just use a free running clock for SCL and SDA is the only thing that makes decisions?  Go low, wait for SCL to go high (SDA still has to watch SCL) then go high creating a STOP.  Stay high and you neither create a stop nor a start.  Wait for SCL high then go low, you create a start, watch scl to drive sda through the transaction, create the stop at the right time, I think it would work so long as it doesnt confuse the peripheral's design.  Maybe the spec says something about this, but that is only marginally relevant as with I2C and SPI, often the spec is ignored by the peripherals.  The peripheral in question dominates as that is who you really want to talk to.  So I think the SCL owner can be as dumb as being just a clock source with no other logic behind it.

Comment: But I2C clock stretching means the clock can't be 'free-running' - when SCL is released to float high by the master, the master has to wait for it to actually go high before continuing.